# Indian national travelling to UK with ricevuta and expired permesso di soggiorno

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, italian-residents, permesso-di-soggiorno, expired

I am an Indian national and I had a 2-year UK multiple-entry visa, which expired last month.

Now I have to travel to the UK in July for an academic ceremony. I will apply for a UK visa again.

But my *permesso di soggiorno* is expired and the date for biometric is in 5 months. Is it possible to travel to the UK and come back to Italy with a *ricevuta* and an expired *permesso di soggiorno*?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to travel to Uk and come back to italy with Ricevuta and expired soggiorno

Since it is for a renewal, you [can travel out of Italy](https://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10722)

> > Foreigners awaiting renewal of their residence permits can leave and re-enter Italy if they hold:
>
> - the receipt issued by Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A) certifying the submission of the application for renewal of their
>   residence permit or EC residence permit for long-term residents;
> - the expired residence permit;
> - their passport or other equivalent travel document .

Note that since you don't have a valid residence permit/visa, you are not allowed to transit through Schengen and must leave/enter Schengen through Italy.

Comment: Thanks you. One more question, if you know about this. I will be travelling with 2 minors with me and It’s mentioned at polizia di Stato that for them a temporary permesso is required! How can I request a temporary permesso for minors? Thanks again! 

Comment: @KhushbooSharma You can go/ask your local [Questura](https://questure.poliziadistato.it/)